# Как найти отличие между файлами XML/словарями?

Tags: python, xml

Мне нужно сравнить 2 XML файла (если есть решение для словарей, то преобразую в словари). Для теста взял 2 копии файла и в одной удалил строку. XMLDIFF выдал кучу проблем, ведь каждая следующая за удаленной строка отличается от строки исходного файла и все идут в виде ошибок. Есть какое-то решение ?

```
MoveNode(node='/svc/id_mail_to[5]', target='/svc[1]', position=20)
MoveNode(node='/svc/id_mail_to[13]', target='/svc[1]', position=25)
MoveNode(node='/svc/id_mail_to_cc[3]', target='/svc[1]', position=27)
MoveNode(node='/svc/id_mail_att_count[1]', target='/svc[1]', position=29)
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_vlan[1]', name='id', value='1')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_gtp_addr[1]', name='v', value='10.10.138.270')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_to[4]', name='v', value='***@mail.ru')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_to[10]', name='id', value='20')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_to[10]', name='v', value='***@mail.ru')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_to[11]', name='id', value='21')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_to[11]', name='v', value='***@yandex.ru')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_to[12]', name='id', value='22')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_to[12]', name='v', value='***@yandex.ru')
RenameNode(node='/svc/id_mail_to[13]', tag='id_mail_to_cc')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_to_cc[3]', name='id', value='25')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_to_cc[3]', name='v', value='***@dmz.ru')
RenameNode(node='/svc/id_mail_to_cc[4]', tag='id_mail_att_count')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_att_count[1]', name='d', value='c')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_att_count[1]', name='id', value='27')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_mail_att_count[1]', name='v', value='1')
RenameNode(node='/svc/id_mail_att_count[2]', tag='id_decoration_count')
UpdateAttrib(node='/svc/id_decoration_count[1]', name='id', value='29')
DeleteAttrib(node='/svc/id_decoration_count[1]', name='d')
DeleteNode(node='/svc/id_decoration_count[2]')
```

Comment: `from difflib import ndiff` подскажет, какие строки удалены, в каких ошибки, какие строки добавлены.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте подсказать xmldiff-у что у вас есть важный атрибут @id, по которому можно отождествлять узлы xml, если изменился их порядок: `xmldiff --unique-attributes id  <file1> <file2>`

Или, при вызове из скрипта:

```
xmldiff.main.diff_files( file1, file2, diff_options={"uniqueattrs":["id"]} )
```

Comment: я использую xmldiff из скрипта, как вызвать ? И как раз не нужно учитывать этот параметр.